# phpExcel stack while trying to save

Tags: php, curl, phpexcel

I am trying to build a script which looks in a database for queued entries and for each one generates and sends an email with an excel report attached.

The script is the following: 
cjob_send_async_reports.php
and it runs through cron job every minute.

```
 <?php 
        error_log('-- START SEND ASYNC',0);
        include realpath(dirname(__FILE__))  . '/../configuration.php';
        $creds = array($rds_fm[0][0],$rds_fm[0][1]);
        $db = db_on($creds);
        $sql = "    SELECT * FROM _itrack_business_async_reports_pro5 WHERE async_status = 1 ORDER BY async_reports_date ASC LIMIT 1";
        try{
            $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->execute();
        }catch(PDOException $ex) {
            itrack_error_log($dbg,$cjob_name,$ex->getMessage(),$sql);
        }

        if($stmt->rowCount() == 1){
            error_log('-- ASYNC REPORT FOUND',0);
            $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $curr_proc  = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
            $id      =  $row['async_reports_id'];
            $reg_id  =  $row['async_reports_register_id'];
            $from    =  $row['async_reports_start_time'];
            $to      =  $row['async_reports_stop_time'];
            $email   =  $row['async_reports_email'];
            $diary   = ($row['async_reports_diary'] == 'yes') ? 'true' : 'false';
            $report  =  $row['async_report'];
            $vehIDs  =  $row['async_vehIDs'];
            $poiIDs  =  $row['async_poiIDs'];

            $xls        = REPORTS_HOST . 'reports/daily_report.php';
                $attrs  = '';
                $attrs .= '?reg_id='.$reg_id;
                $attrs .= '&dev_id='.$vehIDs;
                $attrs .= '&from='.$from;
                $attrs .= '&to='.$to;
                error_log('-- LINK FOR REPORT: ' . $xls . $attrs,0);

            $sql_upd = "    UPDATE  _itrack_business_async_reports_pro5 
                            SET      async_status               =    -1,
                                     async_reports_date_proc    =   '".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."' 
                            WHERE    async_reports_id           =    $id";
            try{
                $stmt_upd = $db->prepare($sql_upd);
                $stmt_upd->execute();
            }catch(PDOException $ex) {
                itrack_error_log($dbg,$cjob_name,$ex->getMessage(),$sql_upd);
            }
            error_log('-- sql_upd: ' . $sql_upd,0);
            error_log('-- PREPARE FOR CURL ',0);

            $ch = curl_init();              
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$xls);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
            $data = array(
                'reg_id'         => $reg_id ,
                'dev_id'         => $vehIDs ,
                'from'           => $from   ,
                'to'             => $to
            );
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
            error_log('-- curl_exec ',0);
            $out = curl_exec($ch);
            if ($out === FALSE) {
                error_log('-- curl_error: ' . curl_error($ch),0);
            }
            curl_close($ch);
            error_log('-- curl_exec DONE ',0);    
            error_log('-- CONNECT AGAIN ON RDS1 ',0);
            $db = db_on($creds);
            $sql_reg = "    SELECT   register_owner,register_language,register_username 
                            FROM    _itrack_business_register 
                            WHERE    register_id = $reg_id";
            try{
                $stmt_reg = $db->prepare($sql_reg);
                $stmt_reg->execute();
            }catch(PDOException $ex) {
                itrack_error_log($dbg,$cjob_name,$ex->getMessage(),$sql_reg);
            }

            $row_reg = $stmt_reg->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            $COMPANY     = $row_reg['register_owner'];
            $lan         = $row_reg['register_language'];
            $username    = $row_reg['register_username'];

            $enable_register = (substr($username,0,8) == "disable-") ? false : true;

            $printingDay = date("d-m-Y H:i");
            $nickname = ''; 
           html_entity_decode(trim($row_dev['devices_nickname']), ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8');
                $filename = "iTrack-Report_[".$nickname."]:(".$from.")-(".$to.").".date('d-m-Y').".xls";
            error_log('-- filename ' . $filename,0);

            $path = realpath(dirname(__FILE__))  . '/../async_reports/';
            file_put_contents($path.$filename,$out);
            error_log('-- SAVE ON: ' . $path,0);

            $file = $path.$filename;
            $file_size = filesize($file);
            error_log('-- file_size: ' . $file_size,0);

                error_log('-- PREPARE TO SEND REPORT ',0);
                $handle = fopen($file, "r");
                $content = fread($handle, $file_size);
                fclose($handle);
                $content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));

                $subject = "iTrack.gr - Automated Reporting System";
                $lng_txt = main_lan($lan);
                $message =  
                '   <html>
                        <head><title>iTrack - Automated Reporting System</title></head>
                        <body>'.$lng_txt[595].$lng_txt[596].'</body>
                    </html>
                ';


                // a random hash will be necessary to send mixed content
                $separator = md5(time());

                // carriage return type (we use a PHP end of line constant)
                $eol = PHP_EOL;

                // main header (multipart mandatory);

                $headers  = "From: iTrack Report Service <alert@itrack.gr>" . $eol;
                $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . $eol;
                $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"" . $separator . "\"" . $eol . $eol;
                $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit" . $eol;
                $headers .= "This is a MIME encoded message." . $eol . $eol;

                // message
                $headers .= "--" . $separator . $eol;
                $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"utf-8\"" . $eol;
                $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit" . $eol . $eol;
                $headers .= $message . $eol . $eol;

                // attachment
                $headers .= "--" . $separator . $eol;
                $headers .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"" . $filename . "\"" . $eol;
                $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64" . $eol;
                $headers .= "Content-Disposition: attachment" . $eol . $eol;
                $headers .= $content . $eol . $eol;
                $headers .= "--" . $separator . "--";

                //SEND Mail

                if($enable_register){
                    echo (mail($email, $subject, "", $headers,'-f alert@itrack.gr')) ? "done!" : "mail send ... ERROR!";
                }
                error_log('-- MAIL SENT ',0);
                $sql_0 = "  UPDATE _itrack_business_async_reports_pro5 
                            SET     async_status            =   0,
                                    async_reports_date_done =   '".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."' 
                            WHERE   async_reports_id        =   ".$id;
                error_log('-- SQL UPDATE: ' . $sql_0,0);
                try{
                    $stmt_0 = $db->prepare($sql_0);
                    $stmt_0->execute();
                }catch(PDOException $ex) {
                    itrack_error_log($dbg,$cjob_name,$ex->getMessage(),$sql_0);
                }
                error_log('-- SQL DONE - REPORT IS OVER ',0);
        }
?>
```

Through curl a web call is made in the php which generates the report. The script is the following:

```
<?php
error_log("start",0);
include realpath(dirname(__FILE__))  . '/../configuration.php';
if(isset($_REQUEST['reg_id'],$_REQUEST['from'],$_REQUEST['to'])){
    $from = $_REQUEST['from'];
    $date_exp = explode(" ",$from);
    $ymd = explode("-",$date_exp[0]);
    if(!checkdate($ymd[1],$ymd[2],$ymd[0])) die('invalid date');
    $to = $_REQUEST['to'];
    $date_exp = explode(" ",$to);
    $ymd = explode("-",$date_exp[0]);
    if(!checkdate($ymd[1],$ymd[2],$ymd[0])) die('invalid date');
    /* fix end date */
    if(strtotime($to) - strtotime($from) > GO_TO_ARCHIVE){
        $to = date("Y-m-d ",strtotime($from . "+10 days"))."23:59:59";
    }
    $reg_id = $_REQUEST['reg_id'];
    $ii = look_up_rds_fm($reg_id);
    $creds = array($rds_fm[$ii][0],$rds_fm[$ii][1]);
    $db = db_on($creds);

    error_log("from = "     . $from     ,0);
    error_log("to = "       . $to       ,0);
    error_log("reg_id = "   . $reg_id   ,0);

    $sql = "    SELECT   register_owner,register_language,register_map,register_subaccounts 
                FROM    _itrack_business_register 
                WHERE    register_id = :reg_id";
    try {
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindValue(':reg_id', $reg_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();
    }catch(PDOException $ex){die("ERROR 1: ".$ex->getMessage());}
    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $lan     = $row['register_language'];
    $owner   = $row['register_owner'];
    $map_url = $row['register_map'];
    $regss   = explode(",",$row['register_subaccounts']);

    $lng_txt = main_lan($lan);

    $dev_id = $_REQUEST['dev_id'];
    $ii = look_up_rds_fm($dev_id,'dev');
    $creds = array($rds_fm[$ii][0],$rds_fm[$ii][1]);
    $db = db_on($creds);

    $sql_dev = "SELECT   devices_id,devices_model,devices_nickname,devices_digital_in,
                         devices_odom,devices_calibration,devices_digital_type,devices_driver,
                         devices_obd 
                FROM    _itrack_business_devices 
                WHERE    devices_id = :dev_id"; 
    try {
        $stmt_dev = $db->prepare($sql_dev);
        $stmt_dev->bindValue(':dev_id', $dev_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt_dev->execute();
    }catch(PDOException $ex){die("error:1-> ".$ex->getMessage());}
    $row_dev = $stmt_dev->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $nickname = html_entity_decode(trim($row_dev['devices_nickname']), ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8');
    $driver   = html_entity_decode((trim($row_dev['devices_driver'])), ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8');
    $stepsForPause = ($row_dev['devices_calibration'] != 1) ? $row_dev['devices_calibration'] : 6;
   $dig_enable = 0;
    $digital_type = $row_dev['devices_digital_type'];
    $din2_name = $din3_name = '';
    $iButtons = array();
    $pois = array();

    $db = select_db_on($dev_id,$from,'dev');
    $KM_WALKED = 0;

    $gmaps = array();

    $gmaps_odom      = ',gmaps_virtual_odometer';
    $gmaps_iButton   = ',gmaps_iButton';
    $gmaps_now       = ',gmaps_now';
    $dig_query       = " ";
    $sql_gmaps = "
        SELECT   gmaps_lat,gmaps_lon,gmaps_engine,gmaps_time,gmaps_geoc,gmaps_temp,gmaps_ovrtemp,
                 gmaps_stop,gmaps_speed,gmaps_lock,gmaps_signal $gmaps_now $gmaps_odom $gmaps_iButton $dig_query 
        FROM    _itrack_business_gmaps 
        WHERE        devices_id  = :dev_id  AND 
                     gmaps_time >= :from    AND 
                     gmaps_time <= :to 
        GROUP BY     gmaps_time 
        ORDER BY     gmaps_time DESC"; 

    try {
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql_gmaps);
        $stmt->bindValue(':dev_id'  , $dev_id   , PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindValue(':from'    , $from     , PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue(':to'      , $to       , PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();
    }catch(PDOException $ex){die("error:5-> ".$ex->getMessage());}


    error_log("done sql"    ,0);
    while($row_gmaps    = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $gmaps[] = array(
            'gmaps_lat'             => $row_gmaps['gmaps_lat'],
            'gmaps_lon'             => $row_gmaps['gmaps_lon'],
            'gmaps_engine'          => $row_gmaps['gmaps_engine'],
            'gmaps_time'            => $row_gmaps['gmaps_time'],
            'gmaps_now'             => $row_gmaps['gmaps_now'],
            'gmaps_geoc'            => $row_gmaps['gmaps_geoc'],
            'gmaps_stop'            => $row_gmaps['gmaps_stop'],
            'gmaps_speed'           => $row_gmaps['gmaps_speed'],
            'gmaps_lock'            => $row_gmaps['gmaps_lock'],
            'gmaps_signal'          => $row_gmaps['gmaps_signal'],
            'gmaps_temp'            => $row_gmaps['gmaps_temp'],
            'gmaps_ovrtemp'         => $row_gmaps['gmaps_ovrtemp'],
            'gmaps_odom'            => '',
            'gmaps_iButton'         => '',
            'gmaps_digital_input2'  => '',
            'gmaps_digital_input3'  => '');
    }
    error_log("array built (". sizeof($gmaps) .")"  ,0);
    $KM_WALKED = $KM_WALKED_LV_CAN;   
    include realpath(dirname(__FILE__))  . '/../assets/excel/PHPExcel.php';

    $styleThickBrownBorderOutline = array('borders' => array('outline' => array('style' => PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_THICK,'color' => array('argb' => '00000000'),),),);
    $styleThinBorder = array('borders' => array('outline' => array('style' => PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_THIN,'color' => array('argb' => '00000000'),),),);

    $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

    // Set Orientation, size and scaling
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getPageSetup()->setOrientation(PHPExcel_Worksheet_PageSetup::ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getPageSetup()->setPaperSize(PHPExcel_Worksheet_PageSetup::PAPERSIZE_A4);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getPageSetup()->setFitToPage(true);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getPageSetup()->setFitToWidth(1);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getPageSetup()->setFitToHeight(0);

    $objDrawing = new PHPExcel_Worksheet_Drawing();

        $ptr_s = 7;
        $ptr   = 8;

    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('I1', $lng_txt[473].":");
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('I1')->getFont()->setBold(true);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('I1')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_RIGHT);

    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('J1', $lng_txt[165]);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('J1')->getFill()->setFillType(PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('J1')->getFill()->getStartColor()->setARGB(PHPExcel_Style_Color::COLOR_RED);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('J1')->getFont()->getColor()->setARGB(PHPExcel_Style_Color::COLOR_WHITE);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('J1')->getFont()->setBold(true);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('J1')->applyFromArray($styleThinBorder);


        $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('J2', $lng_txt[166]);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('J2')->getFill()->setFillType(PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('J2')->getFill()->getStartColor()->setRGB('FF8C00');
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('J2')->getFont()->getColor()->setARGB(PHPExcel_Style_Color::COLOR_WHITE);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('J2')->getFont()->setBold(true);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('J2')->applyFromArray($styleThinBorder);

    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('J3', $lng_txt[474]);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('J3')->getFill()->setFillType(PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('J3')->getFill()->getStartColor()->setARGB(PHPExcel_Style_Color::COLOR_DARKBLUE);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('J3')->getFont()->getColor()->setARGB(PHPExcel_Style_Color::COLOR_WHITE);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('J3')->getFont()->setBold(true);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('J3')->applyFromArray($styleThinBorder);

    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
        ->setCellValue('A'.$ptr_s , $lng_txt[328])
        ->setCellValue('B'.$ptr_s , $lng_txt[376])
        ->setCellValue('C'.$ptr_s , $lng_txt[431])
        ->setCellValue('D'.$ptr_s , $lng_txt[172] . " (km/h)")
        ->setCellValue('E'.$ptr_s , $lng_txt[375])
        ->setCellValue('F'.$ptr_s , 'i-Button')
        ->setCellValue('G'.$ptr_s , $din2_name)
        ->setCellValue('H'.$ptr_s , $din3_name)
        ->setCellValue('I'.$ptr_s , $lng_txt[377])
        ->setCellValue('J'.$ptr_s , $lng_txt[372]."/".$lng_txt[373]);


    $engineSTATUS       = -1;
    $earth_radius       = 6371;
    $adj                = 0;
    $stop_time          = 0;
    $pause_time         = 0;
    $total_stop_time    = 0;
    $total_pause_time   = 0;
    $all_data           = false;
    $pauses_counter     = 0;
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->freezePane('A'.$ptr);

    $sizeofgmaps = sizeof($gmaps);
    if($sizeofgmaps > 3){
        $g = 0;
            $geoc = '';

        addPoint('finish', $gmaps[$g]["gmaps_lat"], $gmaps[$g]["gmaps_lon"], $gmaps[$g]["gmaps_time"], $gmaps[$g]["gmaps_now"], $gmaps[$g]["gmaps_speed"], $gmaps[$g]["gmaps_lock"], $gmaps[$g]["gmaps_signal"], $gmaps[$g]["gmaps_temp"], $gmaps[$g]["gmaps_ovrtemp"], $gmaps[$g]["gmaps_iButton"], $gmaps[$g]["gmaps_digital_input2"],$gmaps[$g]["gmaps_digital_input3"],'',$geoc);

        for($g = 1; $g < $sizeofgmaps - 1; $g++){
            if($gmaps[$g]["gmaps_ovrtemp"] == 1 || $gmaps[$g]["gmaps_lock"] == 1){
                if($stop_time  != 0){
                    $stop_time += abs(strtotime($gmaps[$g]["gmaps_time"]) - strtotime($gmaps[$g-1]["gmaps_time"]));
                    $total_stop_time += $stop_time;
                    $duration   = getDurationCurr($stop_time);
                    $stop_time  = 0;
                        $geoc = ($gmaps[$g]["gmaps_geoc"] != 0 && isset($pois[$gmaps[$g]["gmaps_geoc"]])) ? $pois[$gmaps[$g]["gmaps_geoc"]] : BING_REV_GEOC($gmaps[$g]['gmaps_lat'], $gmaps[$g]['gmaps_lon']);

                    addPoint('stop', $gmaps[$g-1]["gmaps_lat"], $gmaps[$g-1]["gmaps_lon"], $gmaps[$g-1]["gmaps_time"], $gmaps[$g-1]["gmaps_now"], $gmaps[$g-1]["gmaps_speed"], $gmaps[$g-1]["gmaps_lock"], $gmaps[$g-1]["gmaps_signal"], $gmaps[$g-1]["gmaps_temp"], $gmaps[$g-1]["gmaps_ovrtemp"], $gmaps[$g-1]["gmaps_iButton"], $gmaps[$g-1]["gmaps_digital_input2"],$gmaps[$g-1]["gmaps_digital_input3"],$duration,$geoc);
                }

                if($gmaps[$g]["gmaps_engine"] == 0) $mode = 'stop';
                else $mode = 'move';
                    $geoc = ($gmaps[$g]["gmaps_geoc"] != 0 && isset($pois[$gmaps[$g]["gmaps_geoc"]])) ? $pois[$gmaps[$g]["gmaps_geoc"]] : BING_REV_GEOC($gmaps[$g]['gmaps_lat'], $gmaps[$g]['gmaps_lon']);
                addPoint($mode, $gmaps[$g]["gmaps_lat"], $gmaps[$g]["gmaps_lon"], $gmaps[$g]["gmaps_time"], $gmaps[$g]["gmaps_now"], $gmaps[$g]["gmaps_speed"], $gmaps[$g]["gmaps_lock"], $gmaps[$g]["gmaps_signal"], $gmaps[$g]["gmaps_temp"], $gmaps[$g]["gmaps_ovrtemp"], $gmaps[$g]["gmaps_iButton"], $gmaps[$g]["gmaps_digital_input2"],$gmaps[$g]["gmaps_digital_input3"],'',$geoc);
            }
            else if($gmaps[$g]["gmaps_engine"] == 0 && $g < $sizeofgmaps - 2){
                if($pause_time  != 0){
                    $pause_time += abs(strtotime($gmaps[$g]["gmaps_time"]) - strtotime($gmaps[$g-1]["gmaps_time"]));
                    $total_pause_time += $pause_time;
                    $duration    = getDurationCurr($pause_time);
                    $pause_time  = 0;
                        $geoc = ($gmaps[$g]["gmaps_geoc"] != 0 && isset($pois[$gmaps[$g]["gmaps_geoc"]])) ? $pois[$gmaps[$g]["gmaps_geoc"]] : BING_REV_GEOC($gmaps[$g]['gmaps_lat'], $gmaps[$g]['gmaps_lon']);

                    addPoint('pause', $gmaps[$g-1]["gmaps_lat"], $gmaps[$g-1]["gmaps_lon"], $gmaps[$g-1]["gmaps_time"], $gmaps[$g-1]["gmaps_now"], $gmaps[$g-1]["gmaps_speed"], $gmaps[$g-1]["gmaps_lock"], $gmaps[$g-1]["gmaps_signal"], $gmaps[$g-1]["gmaps_temp"], $gmaps[$g-1]["gmaps_ovrtemp"], $gmaps[$g-1]["gmaps_iButton"], $gmaps[$g-1]["gmaps_digital_input2"],$gmaps[$g-1]["gmaps_digital_input3"],$duration,$geoc);
                }
                $stop_time += abs(strtotime($gmaps[$g]["gmaps_time"]) - strtotime($gmaps[$g-1]["gmaps_time"]));
                $engineSTATUS = $gmaps[$g]["gmaps_engine"];
                continue;
            }
            else if($gmaps[$g]["gmaps_engine"] == 1 && $engineSTATUS == 0 && $g < $sizeofgmaps - 2){
                $stop_time += abs(strtotime($gmaps[$g]["gmaps_time"]) - strtotime($gmaps[$g-1]["gmaps_time"]));
                $total_stop_time += $stop_time;
                $duration   = getDurationCurr($stop_time);
                $stop_time  = 0;
                    $geoc = ($gmaps[$g]["gmaps_geoc"] != 0 && isset($pois[$gmaps[$g]["gmaps_geoc"]])) ? $pois[$gmaps[$g]["gmaps_geoc"]] : BING_REV_GEOC($gmaps[$g]['gmaps_lat'], $gmaps[$g]['gmaps_lon']);
                addPoint('stop', $gmaps[$g-1]["gmaps_lat"], $gmaps[$g-1]["gmaps_lon"], $gmaps[$g-1]["gmaps_time"], $gmaps[$g-1]["gmaps_now"], $gmaps[$g-1]["gmaps_speed"], $gmaps[$g-1]["gmaps_lock"], $gmaps[$g-1]["gmaps_signal"], $gmaps[$g-1]["gmaps_temp"], $gmaps[$g-1]["gmaps_ovrtemp"], $gmaps[$g-1]["gmaps_iButton"], $gmaps[$g-1]["gmaps_digital_input2"],$gmaps[$g-1]["gmaps_digital_input3"],$duration,$geoc);
                addPoint('move', $gmaps[$g]["gmaps_lat"], $gmaps[$g]["gmaps_lon"], $gmaps[$g]["gmaps_time"], $gmaps[$g]["gmaps_now"], $gmaps[$g]["gmaps_speed"], $gmaps[$g]["gmaps_lock"], $gmaps[$g]["gmaps_signal"], $gmaps[$g]["gmaps_temp"], $gmaps[$g]["gmaps_ovrtemp"], $gmaps[$g]["gmaps_iButton"], $gmaps[$g]["gmaps_digital_input2"],$gmaps[$g]["gmaps_digital_input3"],'','');
            }
            else if($gmaps[$g]["gmaps_engine"] == 1 && $g < $sizeofgmaps - 2){
                $stop_time  = 0;
                if($pause_time == 0 && !$all_data){
                    $latitude1  = $gmaps[$g]['gmaps_lat'];
                    $longitude1 = $gmaps[$g]['gmaps_lon'];
                    $stop = ($g + $stepsForPause < $sizeofgmaps - 2) ? ($g+$stepsForPause) : $sizeofgmaps - 2;
                    $pauses_counter = 0;
                    for($p = $g+1; $p < $stop; $p++){
                        $latitude2  = $gmaps[$p]['gmaps_lat'];
                        $longitude2 = $gmaps[$p]['gmaps_lon'];

                        $dLat = deg2rad($latitude2 - $latitude1);
                        $dLon = deg2rad($longitude2 - $longitude1);
                        $a = sin($dLat/2) * sin($dLat/2) + cos(deg2rad($latitude1)) * cos(deg2rad($latitude2)) * sin($dLon/2) * sin($dLon/2);
                        $c = 2 * asin(sqrt($a));
                        $d = $earth_radius * $c * 1000;

                        if( $gmaps[$p]["gmaps_engine"] == 1     && 
                            $gmaps[$p]['gmaps_signal'] == 'F'   && 
                            $gmaps[$p]['gmaps_speed']  == 0     && $d < 50 && $p != $g+1
                        ){
                            $pause_time += abs(strtotime($gmaps[$p]["gmaps_time"]) - strtotime($gmaps[$p-1]["gmaps_time"]));
                            $pauses_counter++;
                        }
                    }
                        if($pauses_counter != $stepsForPause-2){
                            $pause_time = 0;
                        }
                        else{
                            $g = $stop-1;
                            continue;
                        }
                }
                else if($pause_time != 0 && !$all_data){
                    $latitude2  = $gmaps[$g]['gmaps_lat'];
                    $longitude2 = $gmaps[$g]['gmaps_lon'];

                    $dLat = deg2rad($latitude2 - $latitude1);
                    $dLon = deg2rad($longitude2 - $longitude1);
                    $a = sin($dLat/2) * sin($dLat/2) + cos(deg2rad($latitude1)) * cos(deg2rad($latitude2)) * sin($dLon/2) * sin($dLon/2);
                    $c = 2 * asin(sqrt($a));
                    $d = $earth_radius * $c * 1000;

                    if( $gmaps[$g]["gmaps_engine"] == 1     && 
                        $gmaps[$g]['gmaps_signal'] == 'F'   && 
                        $gmaps[$g]['gmaps_speed']  == 0     && $d < 50 
                        && !$all_data
                    ){
                        $pause_time += abs(strtotime($gmaps[$g]["gmaps_time"]) - strtotime($gmaps[$g-1]["gmaps_time"]));
                        continue;
                    }
                    else{
                        $pause_time += abs(strtotime($gmaps[$g]["gmaps_time"]) - strtotime($gmaps[$g-1]["gmaps_time"]));
                        $total_pause_time += $pause_time;
                        $duration    = getDurationCurr($pause_time);
                        $pause_time  = 0;
                            $geoc = ($gmaps[$g]["gmaps_geoc"] != 0 && isset($pois[$gmaps[$g]["gmaps_geoc"]])) ? $pois[$gmaps[$g]["gmaps_geoc"]] : BING_REV_GEOC($gmaps[$g]['gmaps_lat'], $gmaps[$g]['gmaps_lon']);
                        addPoint('pause', $gmaps[$g-1]["gmaps_lat"], $gmaps[$g-1]["gmaps_lon"], $gmaps[$g-1]["gmaps_time"], $gmaps[$g-1]["gmaps_now"], $gmaps[$g-1]["gmaps_speed"], $gmaps[$g-1]["gmaps_lock"], $gmaps[$g-1]["gmaps_signal"], $gmaps[$g-1]["gmaps_temp"], $gmaps[$g-1]["gmaps_ovrtemp"], $gmaps[$g-1]["gmaps_iButton"], $gmaps[$g-1]["gmaps_digital_input2"],$gmaps[$g-1]["gmaps_digital_input3"],$duration,$geoc);
                    }
                }
                $geoc = ($gmaps[$g]["gmaps_geoc"] != 0 && isset($pois[$gmaps[$g]["gmaps_geoc"]])) ? $pois[$gmaps[$g]["gmaps_geoc"]] : '';
                addPoint('move', $gmaps[$g]["gmaps_lat"], $gmaps[$g]["gmaps_lon"], $gmaps[$g]["gmaps_time"], $gmaps[$g]["gmaps_now"], $gmaps[$g]["gmaps_speed"], $gmaps[$g]["gmaps_lock"], $gmaps[$g]["gmaps_signal"], $gmaps[$g]["gmaps_temp"], $gmaps[$g]["gmaps_ovrtemp"], $gmaps[$g]["gmaps_iButton"], $gmaps[$g]["gmaps_digital_input2"],$gmaps[$g]["gmaps_digital_input3"],'',$geoc);
            }
            else if($g == $sizeofgmaps - 2){
                if($stop_time  != 0){
                    $stop_time += abs(strtotime($gmaps[$g]["gmaps_time"]) - strtotime($gmaps[$g-1]["gmaps_time"]));
                    $total_stop_time += $stop_time;
                    $duration   = getDurationCurr($stop_time);
                    $stop_time  = 0;
                        $geoc = ($gmaps[$g]["gmaps_geoc"] != 0 && isset($pois[$gmaps[$g]["gmaps_geoc"]])) ? $pois[$gmaps[$g]["gmaps_geoc"]] : BING_REV_GEOC($gmaps[$g]['gmaps_lat'], $gmaps[$g]['gmaps_lon']);
                    addPoint('stop', $gmaps[$g-1]["gmaps_lat"], $gmaps[$g-1]["gmaps_lon"], $gmaps[$g-1]["gmaps_time"], $gmaps[$g-1]["gmaps_now"], $gmaps[$g-1]["gmaps_speed"], $gmaps[$g-1]["gmaps_lock"], $gmaps[$g-1]["gmaps_signal"], $gmaps[$g-1]["gmaps_temp"], $gmaps[$g-1]["gmaps_ovrtemp"], $gmaps[$g-1]["gmaps_iButton"], $gmaps[$g-1]["gmaps_digital_input2"],$gmaps[$g-1]["gmaps_digital_input3"],$duration,$geoc);
                }
                else if($pause_time != 0){
                    $pause_time += abs(strtotime($gmaps[$g]["gmaps_time"]) - strtotime($gmaps[$g-1]["gmaps_time"]));
                    $total_pause_time += $pause_time;
                    $duration    = getDurationCurr($pause_time);
                    $pause_time  = 0;
                        $geoc = ($gmaps[$g]["gmaps_geoc"] != 0 && isset($pois[$gmaps[$g]["gmaps_geoc"]])) ? $pois[$gmaps[$g]["gmaps_geoc"]] : BING_REV_GEOC($gmaps[$g]['gmaps_lat'], $gmaps[$g]['gmaps_lon']);

                    addPoint('pause', $gmaps[$g-1]["gmaps_lat"], $gmaps[$g-1]["gmaps_lon"], $gmaps[$g-1]["gmaps_time"], $gmaps[$g-1]["gmaps_now"], $gmaps[$g-1]["gmaps_speed"], $gmaps[$g-1]["gmaps_lock"], $gmaps[$g-1]["gmaps_signal"], $gmaps[$g-1]["gmaps_temp"], $gmaps[$g-1]["gmaps_ovrtemp"], $gmaps[$g-1]["gmaps_iButton"], $gmaps[$g-1]["gmaps_digital_input2"],$gmaps[$g-1]["gmaps_digital_input3"],$duration,$geoc);
                }
            }
            $engineSTATUS = $gmaps[$g]["gmaps_engine"];
        }
            $geoc = ($gmaps[$g]["gmaps_geoc"] != 0 && isset($pois[$gmaps[$g]["gmaps_geoc"]])) ? $pois[$gmaps[$g]["gmaps_geoc"]] : BING_REV_GEOC($gmaps[$g]['gmaps_lat'], $gmaps[$g]['gmaps_lon']);
        addPoint('start', $gmaps[$g]["gmaps_lat"], $gmaps[$g]["gmaps_lon"], $gmaps[$g]["gmaps_time"], $gmaps[$g]["gmaps_now"], $gmaps[$g]["gmaps_speed"], $gmaps[$g]["gmaps_lock"], $gmaps[$g]["gmaps_signal"], $gmaps[$g]["gmaps_temp"], $gmaps[$g]["gmaps_ovrtemp"], $gmaps[$g]["gmaps_iButton"], $gmaps[$g]["gmaps_digital_input2"],$gmaps[$g]["gmaps_digital_input3"],'',$geoc);
    }

    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('A'.$ptr, '');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A'.$ptr)->getFont()->setBold(true);
    $myName = "iTrack-Report_[".$nickname."]_(".$from.")-(".$to.").".date('d-m-Y').".xls";
    error_log("excel is over"   ,0);
    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
    error_log("header 1",0);
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename='.$myName);
    error_log("header 2",0);
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
    error_log("header 3",0);
    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
    error_log("objWriter 1",0);
    SaveViaTempFile($objWriter);
    error_log("objWriter 2",0);
}
function SaveViaTempFile($objWriter){
    $filePath = '/tmp/' . rand(0, getrandmax()) . rand(0, getrandmax()) . ".tmp";
    $objWriter->save($filePath);
    readfile($filePath);
    unlink($filePath);
}
function addPoint($mode, $lat, $lon, $gtime, $gnow, $speed, $lock, $signal, $temp, $ovrtemp, $iButton, $dig2, $dig3, $duration, $geoc){
    global $map_url,$ptr,$objPHPExcel,$styleThickBrownBorderOutline,$lng_txt,$din2_name,$din3_name,$styleThinBorder,$dig_enable,$digital_type;
         if($mode == 'finish')                  $mode_txt = $lng_txt[514];
    else if($mode == 'start')                   $mode_txt = $lng_txt[515];
    else if($mode == 'stop')                    $mode_txt = $lng_txt[395];
    else if($mode == 'move' && $speed == 0)     $mode_txt = $lng_txt[383];
    else if($mode == 'move')                    $mode_txt = $lng_txt[380];
    else if($mode == 'pause')                   $mode_txt = $lng_txt[393];
    else                                        $mode_txt = '';

    $temp = round($temp,1);

    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('A'.$ptr , date("d/m/Y H:i", strtotime($gtime)))->setCellValue('B'.$ptr , $mode_txt)->setCellValue('C'.$ptr , $duration)->setCellValue('D'.$ptr , round($speed,0))->setCellValue('E'.$ptr , $temp)->setCellValue('F'.$ptr , $iButton)->setCellValue('G'.$ptr , $dig2)->setCellValue('H'.$ptr , $dig3)->setCellValue('I'.$ptr , $geoc);    
    if(($gnow != '') && abs(strtotime($gnow) - strtotime($gtime)) > 300){
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A'.$ptr)->getFont()->setItalic(true);
    }

        $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('J'.$ptr , round($lat,5)."/".round($lon,5)); // Γ.Πλάτος/Γ.Μήκος
        $url = (isset($map_url) && $map_url == 'bingv7') 
        ? 'http://www.bing.com/maps/default.aspx?cp='.$lat.'~'.$lon.'&style=o&lvl=1&dir=0&scene=1140291'
        : 'https://www.google.com/maps?f=q&q='.$lat.','.$lon ;
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('J'.$ptr)->getHyperlink()->setUrl($url);
    $ptr++;
}
?>
```

My problem is that the command  **$objWriter->save($filePath);** never ends. It seems that for a reason that I can't figure out it stacks here and as a result the procedure can not go on. Does anybody have any idea what is going on?

-- additional info 
-- PHP Version 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.16
-- Apache Version   Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)

Comment: how many rows do you have? i had issues with excel and big tables because it was writing doc on cell by cell basis. we replaced it w/ TBS (tiny but Strong) which solved it like a charm.

Comment: about 2000 rows. Does it have any impact?

Comment: not sure ... for test, you could try limiting result set to 10 and checking if it helps.